# Need help with simple algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been stuck at this simple algebra question for quite a while already. I would appreciate some help.

Given that:

*a* + *b* + *c* + *d* + *e* = 200

*a* + *c* + *d* = 85.841

2*d* + 2*e* = *a*

find the value of ***c* + 2*d***.

Thanks.

Comment: looking at it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are infinitely many solution of this question. One of them is a=60, b=104.159, c=5.841, d=20, e=10. Just take any value(in range) of d and e you will get a then you will get c and then b. Three of the equation will be satisfied.

Comment: They didn't ask to solve the system (find the values for a, b, c, d, e). The question is to manipulate these equations to get the equation c + 2d = something.

Comment: For different solution of the system  value of c+2d will also change. So answer will remain infinite.